# senkeys() in silenium throughing error while having added all build path and having jdk 8

Tags: java, selenium, sendkeys

Im beginner in selenium , installed properly with JDK 8 and silenum 2.52 ,getting this error repeatedly . Cnt go forward . Please help me out .

```
The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

Java Problem

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Cheese!");
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Cheese!");
```

Comment: not working , while writting .sendkeys() its giving error .

Comment: Get solved , I have used JRE 7, Earlier I using JRE 8 .